# how QT to transmit string "E:\test\test.exe" to "E:/test/test.exe"

Tags: qt, path

windows's dir path is like this

> "E:\test\test.exe"

how could I transmit it to

> "E:/test/test.exe".

I do not want to transmit like follow:

> "E:\test\test.exe" --> "E:\test\test.exe" --> "E:/test/test.exe"

Comment: What do you mean by "transmit" ?

Comment: use some methods to turn the string "E:\test\test.exe" to another string "E:/test/test.exe"

Answer (score 0):

Try using QFileInfo class, it gives u very covenient methods for dealing with file paths.

```
QString filename= "E:test/test.exe";
QFileInfo myFileinfo(filename);

myFileinfo.absoluteFilePath();// E:test/test.exe
myFileinfo.fileName();// test.exe
```

Comment: the source string is "E:\test\test.exe", I hope turn it to "E:/test/test.exe"

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just replace slashes?

```
QString filename= "E:\\test\\test.exe";
filename.replace(QChar('\\'),QChar('/'));
```

Comment: because the source string just has one slashes：
`"E:\test\test.exe"`

Comment: "\t" is an tabulator character. If you really have only one slash in your code you have string like this: "E:    est    est.exe"  QChar('\\') will be converted by compiler to "\" and QString filename= "E:\\test\\test.exe"; to "E:\test\test.exe"; Just test it. And don't use qDebug to output "E:\\test\\test.exe" it adds extra slashes, use printf or print in log file

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [QDir::fromNativeSeparators()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#fromNativeSeparators) and [QDir::toNativeSeparators()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#toNativeSeparators).